# Lock table for reading and writing

Tags: php, mysql

How to lock table for reading and writing with php? Here is what I tried without luck.

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES table WRITE;");
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES table READ, WRITE;");
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES table READ WRITE;");
```

Here is the error I got:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WRITE' at line 1

Comment: well the first statement should just be fine. What is it that does not work? Is it giving an error? Does it not put the WRITE lock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLE table WRITE"); // you might think it's here
mysql_query("LOCK TABLE table READ, table AS t2 WRITE"); // <- but the error is here
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES table READ, table as t2 WRITE"); // <- ...and here.
```

You can not acquire multiple locks for the same table without aliasing it. [Read the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html).