# How do I prevent people from opening a record if someone else has it open?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I'm creating a PHP Web application, which would involve:

1) Users opening a record

2) Users making changes to the record

3) Saving changes to the record

Since this is a multi-user application, I want to prevent situations where two users have the same record open at the same time, and one user's changes overwrites the next, preferrably by enforcing some sort of locking method when a record is opened that automatically unlocks when the user navigates away from the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lock table for reading and writing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981688/lock-table-for-reading-and-writing)

Comment: Use MySQL Locks: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: @j08691: Not really a duplicate since the question linked talks about locking the entire table, and not just a single record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By record, you mean SQL records? If so, you could add another column `isOpen`. Set it to `1` as long as someone else has it open, and in that case, do not serve it to anyone else.

In situations like this, it works best to also implement a timeout mechanism, where a record can be open only for 'x' min before being forcibly closed.

(Edit: This answer is assuming you want to keep a record locked the entire duration a user is viewing the info fetched from the table. If you want to lock a record only for the instant that a read/write operation is occuring on that record, MySQL engines have inbuilt mechanisms for that)

**In response to your comment**

To make a record accessible to others when the active user navigates away, off the top of my head, I can think of two ways to achieve it:

- Allow the timeout mechanism to take care of it. Depending on your scenario, a short enough time window could work fine.
- In addition to the timeout, also implement a heartbeat mechanism - an Ajax script on the page polls the server letting it know the page is still open. If the user navigates away, the server recognizes the skipped heartbeat, and unsets the record. In this case, the timeout would still take precedence. So, if the user leaves the window open and walks away, the server would still receive the heartbeat, but when the time window closes, the server unsets the record (despite still receiving heartbeats).

Comment: I've thought of this, but what would happen if the user simply navigates away from the record without saving it? Would there be a way to unset the 'isOpen' when the user leaves the page, or must I solely rely on a timeout mechanism for that?

Comment: A less intrusive approach (user experience wise) would be not to forbid the second user clicking the Edit button from saving the record, but just inform him that another user (maybe even specify who, depending of the application business) just opened that record for editing.

Comment: check out the `unload` event - you can tell when a user has navigated away from a page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload might help with unlocking

Comment: Instead of a simple flag, I'd use a "locked since" column and stick a timestamp in there.  You could use that as an optimistic lock counter (user can still update if timestamp matches) and you don't need any complicated timers.  You don't even need to clear it, just add a `(now - locked_since) > timeout` clause to your select statements and it'll always DTRT.

Answer (score 2):

I use a field `update_date`. When user reads the record I write a cookie with this date. When user updates the record and submits the new data I'am adding `WHERE update_date = '$my_escaped_date' AND id = '$the_edited_id'` and if `mysql_affected_rows` is zero I'm showing error message that the edited data is old. It's not perfect as if you edit old data you must reenter it, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

A locking method is exactly what is available in mysql:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

It's not automatic but it allows you to lock a table, do stuff and then unlock it again.

Be carefull tho' that the system does not become locked up if you forget to unlock a table or a user takes a long time to change something and you only unlock it when that user submits the form.

A better way might be to read data from the table and upon submission of the form, check to see if the data has not been altered. If it has you can notify the user of the changes and other wise you can lock the table, perform the changes and unlock it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field `in_use` to the records table,
when a user open that record update its value to 1 and when he saves it
update it back to 0.

If the value is 1 - the record is locked and won't be opened for other users.